# Can a preposition modifies a prepositional phrase?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

> Unless an order from the Reading Nook's online store is paid ***for by*** the deadline indicated, the books cannot be shipped and the order will be canceled.

Can a preposition modifies a prepositional phrase like the above sentence? I have learned that preposition phrases are adverbs or adjectives and prepositions modify nouns only.

Comment: PPs can be complement or modifier of a preposition, as in "I stayed [until [after lunch]" and "[According [to Ed], it's a great car". But this is not the case in your example, where the PP "by the deadline indicated" is complement of the verb "paid", not of the preposition "for". In other words, "paid" has two separate PP complements: "for" and "by the deadline indicated", where the latter is a temporal adjunct in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ Then, is this sentence same that paid for (something = an order) by the deadline indicated?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know enough to answer the question in the title, but I'm making a post anyway because this is not a case of a preposition modifying a prepositional phrase.

The sentence that you quote is an example of a "[prepositional passive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Prepositional_passive)". The equivalent sentence in the active voice would be of the form "Unless [someone] **pays for** an order from the Reading Nook's online store **by the deadline indicated**, the books cannot be shipped and the order will be canceled."

I hope this makes it clear that the prepositional phrase starting with "by" modifies the verb "pays".

Answer (score 2):

> *Unless an order from the Reading Nook's online store is paid for by*
>   *the deadline indicated, the books cannot be shipped and the order will*
>   *be canceled.*

PPs can be complement or modifier of a preposition, as in *I stayed* [*until* [*after lunch*] and [*According* [*to Ed*], *it's a great car*. But this is not the case in your example, where the PP *by the deadline indicated* is complement of the verb *paid*, not of the preposition *for*. In other words, *paid* has two separate PP complements: *for* and *by the deadline indicated*, where the latter is a temporal adjunct in clause structure.

The *unless* phrase is a conditional, equivalent to an *if* conditional with a negative protasis. Cf. *If an order from the Reading Nook's online store is not paid for by the deadline indicated, the books cannot be shipped and the order will be cancelled.*